# How can I use a reduce to avoid iterating through an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, reduce

I have:

```
  const weekdays = eachDay.map((day) => format(day, 'EEE'));

  let ret = { Su: '', Mo: '', Tu: '', We: '', Th: '', Fr: '', Sa: '' };
  weekdays.forEach((day, index) => {
    ret[Object.keys(ret)[index] as DaysOfWeekMui] = day;
  });
```

One of my teammates said that I could use a `reduce` to avoid predefining the `ret`. But I'm not sure what he means. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it depends on what `eachDay` looks like. Post your input data for more complete help.

Comment: You have this tagged Javascript not Typescript, and yet that appears to be a type cast in there?

Comment: No point in using `reduce` when you really want to modify that object.

Comment: You probably should be using `Object.fromEntries` instead anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `reduce` mostly when I want to transform a list of things into a single thing.

So from your example you are iterating over a list of `weekdays` and turning it into an object.

To rewrite your existing code you would use reduce like this:

```
const ret = weekdays.reduce((acc, day) => {
   return { ...acc, [day.slice(0, 2)]: day }
}, /* initial value: */ {})
```

This code will iterate over your weekdays and calling the reduce function. The function receives `acc` which is the result from the last iteration (or the initial value in the first iteration) as well as the `item` from the list you are calling reduce on.

Given a list of: `["Monday", "Tuesday"]` the result of the `reduce` function will be:

```
{
  Mo: "Monday",
  Tu: "Tuesday"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) takes two arguments: a callback and an initial value. In your case, `ret` would be your initial value, and your code could be refactored as such:

```
const ret = weekdays.reduce((obj, day, index) => {
  obj[obj.keys(obj)[index] as DaysOfWeekMui] = day
  return obj
}, { Su: '', Mo: '', Tu: '', We: '', Th: '', Fr: '', Sa: '' })
```